# Code using Entity Framework not calling jquery ajax's success function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jquery

I have two alternative methods to retreive data from Database.

1)using Ado.net

```
public List<Customer> GetDetail()
{
    SqlConnection connectionstring = new SqlConnection(connectionstring goes on..);
    List<Customer> custList = new List<Customer>();

    connectionstring.Open();

        string query = "select * from Customer";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connectionstring);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Customer cust = new Customer();
                cust.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                cust.UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                cust.CountryId = reader["CountryId"].ToString();
                cust.EmailId = reader["EmailId"].ToString();
                cust.PhoneNo = reader["PhoneNo"].ToString();
                custList.Add(cust);
            }
        }
    connectionstring.Close();
    return custList;
}
```

2)using Entity Framework

```
        public List <Customer> GetDetail()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();

            CustomerEntities context = new CustomerEntities(GetConnectionObject());
            foreach (Customer cus in context.Customers)
            {
                CustomerList.Add(cus);
            }
            return CustomerList;
        }
```

Am calling the controller method using jquery ajax call, which calls the above methods.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Customer/GetDetails",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false, 
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
            $.each(data, function (index, customer) {
                alert(customer.Name + " " + customer.UserName);
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
                alert("oooppss");
            }
            else { alert("something went wrong"); }
        }
    });
```

If it is normal ado.net code, its successfully retreiving the data and the ajax success function is getting called.

But if it is entity framework method, even though it is retreiving the data(while debugging, I can see the resultened data in the customerList object), the ajax success function is not getting called. Instead, error function is getting called. The errorThrown is "Internal server error".

Why? What is the wrong with Entity framework?

Could anyone please give solution for this..?

Comment: what error you are getting in the error method of jQuery?

Comment: for EF you aren't using the dt. Also you should just "return context.Customers.ToList()"

Comment: Does the Customer class have any associations? It could well be a serialisation issue. Check that the type of cus is of type Customer, rather than that of the EF proxy type. If it is a proxy class then you need to turn off UseProxy on the config of the CustomerEntities object.

Comment: @Shekar The error thrown is "Internal server error"

Comment: @Aron Yes. My customer object have a association with another entity called Country.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework creates objects that can't be serialised (since they support lazy loading, serialising them could in effect mean serialising your database). To stop this behavior you need to turn off Lazy Loading completely

```
            context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Insert this before you make the database query, and if the problem persists call me in the morning.

Comment: Sorry.. Am getting error by implementing your code stating like Configuration is not defined. Then, I found that 'ObjectContextOptions' class has the property 'ProxyCreationEnabled'.              ObjectContextOptions cont=new ObjectContextOptions();
            cont.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            cont.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;                          But how to map this object to my CustomerEntities object? How both will get related?

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were using EF5 DbContexts. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

compare both customer list collection and check if there any difference.. may be the return object creating problem...
Or
Use Using keyword in CustomerEntities.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
```

And see what is the error coming.

 There can be many error.

Comment: Xhr.status - 500 thrownError is "Internal server error" responseText states that "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'EF.Customer'."

Answer (score 0):

New Code for EF Creats object for Json Return You have to must 
ensure this code first.

```
            dbcontext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            dbcontext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```